# Dynamic twitter-follow-button

Tags: jquery, button, twitter

Hey there i tried to create a twitter-follow-button, which gets his content via jQuery:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gmq39/22/

I also included:

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
```

If you click at the link, a modalbox appear´s, but the twitter-button doesnt work correct and the style is wrong too.

Anybody know´s a workaround or what do i need to inlcude?

Comment: if you add `target="_blank"` to the link it'll work. I'm not sure if it's accetable. http://fiddle.jshell.net/gmq39/24/